# Expected '(' but got identifier in line 10

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

library Groups {

    struct Group {
        mapping(address => bool) members;

        function addMember( Group storage self, address addr ) public returns (bool) { // error
            if(self.members[addr]) {
                return false;
            }
            self.members[addr] = true;
            return true;
        }

        function delMember( Group storage self, address addr ) public returns (bool) {
            if(self.members[addr]) {
                return false;
            }
            self.members[addr] = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(self.members[addr] == true) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
mapping(address => bool) members;

function addMember(address _address) public {
 require(members[_address] == false, "Member is already listed");
 members[_address] == true;
}

function removeMember(address _address) public {
 require(members[_address] == true, "Address is already out");
members[_address] == true;
}

function memberStatus(address _address) public returns(bool){
 return members[_address];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please close the struct before writing your functions, don't add functions inside struct , this might help

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library Groups {
    struct Group {
    mapping(address => bool) members;
    }

    function addMember( Group storage self, address addr ) public returns (bool) { // error
        if(self.members[addr]) {
            return false;
        }
        self.members[addr] = true;
        return true;
    }

    function delMember( Group storage self, address addr ) public returns (bool) {
        if(self.members[addr]) {
            return false;
        }
        self.members[addr] = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```